# Is there a way to set a timeout in Java with Redis reactive?

Tags: java, spring-webflux, spring-data-redis-reactive

I'm using `ReactiveRedisConnection` to configure a connection to a local redis container.

But in the future the application will be hosted on a webserver and the redis on a different server.

Is there any option to set a timeout for a request?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some research and tests, I found that the timeout must be set on the request query instead.

So on the config Class:

```
@Bean
public ReactiveRedisTemplate<String, String> reactiveRedisTemplateString
(ReactiveRedisConnectionFactory connectionFactory) {
    return new ReactiveRedisTemplate<>
              (connectionFactory, RedisSerializationContext.string());
}
```

and in the service:

```
@Autowired
private ReactiveRedisTemplate<String, Response> repository;
```

```
public Mono<String> execute(String value){
        return repository.opsForHash().entries("KEY_TO_SEARCH")
                .timeout(Duration.ofMillis(TIMEOUT))
                .collect(Collectors.toMap("CODE_HERE");
```

Edit: Thank for everyone who helped here.

Answer (score 0):

Timeout can be configured on your Reactive Connection Implementation. If you are using Lettuce for Redis Connection, you can do the following.

```
@Bean
public ReactiveRedisConnectionFactory reactiveRedisConnectionFactory() {
    return new LettuceConnectionFactory(new RedisStandaloneConfiguration(), LettuceClientConfiguration.builder().commandTimeout(Duration.ofSeconds(2)).build());
}
```

And then use the `connectionFactory` to create `ReactiveRedisTemplate`.

```
@Bean
public ReactiveRedisTemplate<String, String> reactiveRedisTemplateString
  (ReactiveRedisConnectionFactory connectionFactory) {
    return new ReactiveRedisTemplate<>(connectionFactory, RedisSerializationContext.string());
}
```

Comment: Whatever I set, it is taking 10 seconds.